# Angular 2 - url with assets

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

Basically, my problem is this:

When I try to do a url to a css file for example like this:

```
<link href="app/css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

the link doesn't find the file, only if the css file is inside the "assets" folder or inside the "app" folder for example: `<link href="assets/css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet">` or `<link href="app/reset.css" rel="stylesheet">` does work.

I don't know why, the import of all the models and such works without a problem, only css and json files (from what I tested for now) even in a get or post request.
Thank you all for helping.

Comment: are you using any build system ? `gulp` etc ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Angular CLI you either have two options:

You can add the path of the CSS-file to the `.angular-cli.json` file in the `apps[0].styles` section.

Or you can import the CSS-file in your `styles.scss` file (assuming you are using SCSS).

```
@import './../your_file_path/your_file_name.css';
```

Answer (score 1):

1) First, of all no need to add extra css files, you can write your css in 
  `styles.css` or `app.component.css` or each component have their own css.

2) If you want to use external css libraries of `bootstrap` etc you can install 
   with  `npm` and pass reference of the css in `angular-cli.json in styles 
   section`.

3) You can put all your css files in `assets folder` and pass reference in 
   `angular-cli.json`(same as 2)

Answer (score 1):

addition to above, you can drop css to assets directory or you can add item to assets setting item as below:

```
"assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico",
    { "glob": "**/*", "input": "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist", "output": "./dist" },
    { "glob": "**/*", "input": "../node_modules/ionicons/dist", "output": "./dist" },
    { "glob": "**/*", "input": "../node_modules/admin-lte/dist", "output": "./dist" }
  ],
```